# How to handle mutually dependant components to avoid circular dependency warning in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

When it comes to services and modules its clear. Either forwardRef, Injector or Shared Module. But if there are 2 components
Components A has components B
and
Components B has components A

Then you facing a WARNING in Circular dependency.

Any ideas how to handle it?

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome to see how you implemented the "has-a" relation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really handle it. You can't ask two services to depends on each other. And Service in Angular are created when the app is created. So they are created at the same time. If there is a circular dependancy that mean there is a problem in your logic. I imagine that you need to update a variable in both Service (ex: a user model).
Let's have this : 
Auth.service → will update the user model through a subject and need other Service to update another subject or for a special function (so you need to import Other.Service)
Other.service → need the user model (so you need to import the Auth.Service)

This schema can't work.

What you can do in this example it's removing the need of the user model in Other.Service and you can by this import OtherService in the Auth.Service.

For more help, need to have more information.  Hope it helps.

Comment: The logic is fine... Its not the first time when this problem occurs. The easiest example where you always will have Circular Dependency  is authentication and http interceptors... Authentication requires http, http requires authentication.. But with services you can easily use Injector and problem is solved. Components are different

Comment: @Timothy do you have a concrete example ?